# Share session between ashx and aspx

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I have an ashx file (implementing the IRequiresSessionState interface) storing a value to session state like so:

```
context.Session.Add("answer", _answer);
```

In the code-behind of the aspx file which triggers the ashx call I try to access the session variable like so:

```
Context.Session["answer"].ToString()
```

and I get a NullReferenceException.

How do I need to go about writing and reading from session state in this context?

Comment: I've created exactly what you describe and I don't see the issue.  There must be something else going on.  Do you have details about what throws the NullReferenceException?  Can you confirm that the "answer" value is not null when you set it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I susspect that the issue is on url name and in the setup of your cookies on the session, because if you have place the IRequiresSessionState interface you sould read the session.

Go to your web.config and set your domain name on the httpCookies as your name of your domain with out the 'www'.

```
<httpCookies domain="domainname.com" .... />
```

This way your page reads the cookie and the session ether you call it from domainname.com, ether www.domainname.com.