# Session expired error on login

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-applications, web-hosting

We have two windows servers for different environment where the applications are hosted on IISv6.

I host a new site on **server one** .When we try to login to **server one**, application through exception `SESSION  IS GETTING EXPIRED` immediately on login button clicks.

We have same binaries on **server two** and its working fine there.

One more surprise is that same application was hosted 2-3 months earlier and working fine on **server one**.

The works that I did:

1. I compared IIS setting on both server.
2. Re-host website for 2-3 times.
3. Clear cookies on browser.
4. Play with session timeout and execution timeout.
5. Authorization is also enabled for anonymous.

Both server and client machine time are the same

I would like to know, if someone faced the same issue here.

Thanks

Comment: Try reformatting your question so it is easier to read.

Comment: take a look on this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703423/share-session-between-ashx-and-aspx/6705939#6705939