# WebMethod returns null HttpSession variable (while others don't)

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod, httpsession

I have this code behind aspx which has WebMethods to receive data from AJAX requests. All of the methods can access HttpSession variables except this one I just created which returns null.

The main difference between this new one and the ones that can access the data is the former receives data from an external node.js app while all the others get their input from JavaScript code which sends client side variables.

This is the method (from another class) that I use to access the HttpContext variables:

```
internal static string GetUser()
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.Session[User] as string;
        }
```

Comment: is it possible that the type of the value returned by `HttpContext.Current.Session[User]` is not a string, but some other type of object? If so, the `as string` will create a null.

Comment: It is a string and works well in any other case

Comment: It that is correct, then `(string)HttpContext.Current.Session[User]` should be a safe replacement. If that throws a typecast exception, then your assumption is wrong.

Comment: No exception thrown, same result

Answer (score 1):

**Usually** if you are unable to read the session data, then **the issue is on the cookie**, because the cookie is connect the session with the user.

So check the cookies settings, and if you are have the same cookie across calls. Eg if you have `www.domain.com` cookie and you make a request from `domain.com` or vise versa, or from secure page to non secure page and the cookie if force to be secure, all of that can make issues.

So try also on `web.config` to set your domain with out the `www.`, and check the rest that I mention.

```
<httpCookies domain="domainname.com" .... />
```

### related

[Share session between ashx and aspx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6703423/share-session-between-ashx-and-aspx/6705939#6705939)